# Generating one New string By the given Regex

Tags: java

Here i have attached one regex `"^0*(?=([1-9])0*([1-9])0*([1-9])0*([1-9]))[0-9]([1-9])0([1-9])0*([1-9])0*([1-9])0*$"`.

Will it be possible to generate the string from this regex or from any other combination of that particular regex?

**Eg:**
Suppose I am taking string 12304050. after trimming 0's the string will be 12345.Then first four is 1234 and last four is 2345 and after concatenating it will be 12342345.

Comment: You'd have to parse your regex (with another regex?) and generate inputs for each capturing group...

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to trim 0's using `replaceAll` and to extract the first and last for digits using `substring`?

Comment: Why complicate things using regex?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will help you.

```
String input="12304050";

        String firstFourChars = "";
        String lastFourDigits = "";     

        String trimmedWithZero=input.replaceAll("0","");

        firstFourChars = trimmedWithZero.substring(0, 4);

        lastFourDigits = trimmedWithZero.substring(trimmedWithZero.length() - 4);


        System.out.println(firstFourChars+""+lastFourDigits);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is a bad tool to solve this (at least in the way you are doing it).
As stated by DanielJunglas you should operate differently to achieve your goal simpler and faster:

```
String myInput = "12304050";
String zeroTrim = myInput.replaceAll("0", "");
int length = zeroTrim.length;
String firstFour = zeroTrim.substring(0, 4);
String lastFour = zeroTrim.substring(length - 4);
String concat = firstFour + lastFour;
```

If you want, you cann include an assertion, that the characters in `firstFour` and `lastFour` are all numbers.